# Selecting TreeView values based on a many to many relationships in a razor pages model

Tags: c#, razor, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have a Razor pages project that is trying to populate a Kendo TreeView (or any other TreeView) from a Database created with a Data Model.

The page I am working on contains apps that are in use, and the tree is reading a self referencing Organisations list so that we know what apps each organisation or department etc has access to.
I'm working on the Edit page in a razor app, so ~Pages\Apps\Edit.cshtml and ~Pages\Apps\Edit.cshtml.cs, with associated model pages as shown below.
These are the models involved, ignore RoleApps for this issue:

```
namespace FliveRetry.Models
{
    public class Org
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string OrgName { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        public bool? HasChildren { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace FliveRetry.Models
{
    public class App
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AppName { get; set; }
        public string AppDescription { get; set; }
        public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool? Archived { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Saved { get; set; }
        public int? SavedBy { get; set; }


        public ICollection<OrgAppJoin> OrgAppJoins { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleAppJoin> RoleAppJoins { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the index model:

```
{
    public class AppIndexData
    {       

        public IEnumerable<App> Apps { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Org> Orgs { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<RoleAppJoin> RoleAppJoins { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OrgAppJoin> OrgAppJoins { get; set; }
    }
    public class AssignedAppOrgData
    {
        public int OrgID { get; set; }
        public string Org { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        public bool Assigned { get; set; }
        public bool? HasChildren { get; set; }
    }
    public class SelectedAppOrgs
    {
        public int OrgID { get; set; }
    }
    public class SelectedAppOrgNames
    {
        public string OrgName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a page model to populate selected items into lists called selectedOrgs or selectedOrgNames that I can use in the view.

```
 public class AppSelectPageModel : PageModel
    {

        //Load list for Selecting Orgs for Apps
        public List<AssignedAppOrgData> AssignedAppOrgDataList;
        public List<SelectedAppOrgs> selectedOrgs;
        public List<SelectedAppOrgNames> selectedOrgNames;
        public void PopulateAssignedAppOrgData(FliveRetryContext context, App app)
        {
            var allOrgs = context.Org;
            var appOrgs = new HashSet<int>(
                app.OrgAppJoins.Select(c => c.OrgID));
            AssignedAppOrgDataList = new List<AssignedAppOrgData>();
            selectedOrgs = new List<SelectedAppOrgs>();
            selectedOrgNames = new List<SelectedAppOrgNames>();
            foreach (var org in allOrgs)
            {
                AssignedAppOrgDataList.Add(new AssignedAppOrgData
                {
                    OrgID = org.ID,
                    Org = org.OrgName,
                    Assigned = appOrgs.Contains(org.ID)  
                });
                if (appOrgs.Contains(org.ID))
                {
                    selectedOrgs.Add(new SelectedAppOrgs
                    {
                        OrgID = org.ID
                    });
                    selectedOrgNames.Add(new SelectedAppOrgNames
                    {
                        OrgName = org.OrgName
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        public void UpdateAppOrgs(FliveRetryContext context,
            string[] selectedOrgs, App appToUpdate)
        {
            if (selectedOrgs == null)
            {
                appToUpdate.OrgAppJoins = new List<OrgAppJoin>();
                return;
            }
            var selectedOrgsHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedOrgs);
            var appOrgs = new HashSet<int>
                (appToUpdate.OrgAppJoins.Select(c => c.Org.ID));

            foreach (var org in context.Org)
            {
                if (selectedOrgsHS.Contains(org.OrgName.ToString()))
                {
                    if (!appOrgs.Contains(org.ID))
                    {
                    appToUpdate.OrgAppJoins.Add(
                        new OrgAppJoin
                        {
                            AppID = appToUpdate.ID,
                            OrgID = org.ID
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (appOrgs.Contains(org.ID))
                    {
                        OrgAppJoin orgToRemove
                            = appToUpdate
                                .OrgAppJoins
                                .SingleOrDefault(i => i.OrgID == org.ID);
                        context.Remove(orgToRemove);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I then process them in OnGetAsync in Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            this.TreeData = GetOrgTreeData();

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            App = await _context.App
                .Include(i => i.OrgAppJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.Org)
                .Include(i => i.RoleAppJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.Role)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

            if (App == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            PopulateAssignedAppRoleData(_context, App);
            PopulateAssignedAppOrgData(_context, App);
            return Page();
        }
```

and OnPostAsync

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id, string[] selectedOrgs, string[] selectedRoles)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }


            var appToUpdate = await _context.App
                .Include(i => i.OrgAppJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.Org)
                .Include(i => i.RoleAppJoins).ThenInclude(i => i.Role)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ID == id);


            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<App>(
                 appToUpdate,
                 "app",   // Prefix for form value.
                   c => c.AppName, c => c.AppDescription, c => c.DisplayOrder))
            {
                UpdateAppOrgs(_context, selectedOrgs, appToUpdate);

                UpdateAppRoles(_context, selectedRoles, appToUpdate);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            UpdateAppOrgs(_context, selectedOrgs, appToUpdate);
            UpdateAppRoles(_context, selectedRoles, appToUpdate);

            PopulateAssignedAppOrgData(_context, App);
            PopulateAssignedAppRoleData(_context, App);
            return Page();

        }
```

This works fine when using multiselect dropdowns and reads and writes correctly to the many to many join tables.
I am using kendo controls at the moment, but I'm happy to use generic if I can find a solution to my problem.
I need to have a treeview for the Org model to display as a multi select, so I have two examples I am trying to get working, that behave differently, the DropDownTreeview is not essential but in some pages it will be handy, the TreeView is essential. 
The first is the TreeView:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                           .Name("selectedOrgNames")
                           .DataTextField("OrgName")
                           .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                                      .Name("ischecked")
                                      .CheckChildren(true))
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                           .DataSource(d => d
                               .Read(read =>
                                   read.Url("/Apps/Edit?handler=Read")
                               )
                           )
                        )
```

The second is the DropDownTreeview:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownTree()
                               .Placeholder("Select ...")
                               .Name("selectedOrgs")
                               .DataTextField("OrgName")
                               .DataValueField("ID")
                               .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                                          .Name("ischecked")
                                          .CheckChildren(true))
                               .AutoClose(false)
                               .Value(Model.selectedOrgNames)
                               .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                               .DataSource(d => d
                                   .Read(read =>
                                       read.Url("/Apps/Edit?handler=Read")
                                   )
                               )
                        )
```

Both examples read the datasource from here in edit.cshtml.cs:

```
public IActionResult OnGetRead(int? id)
        {
            var result = from e in _context.Org
                                where id.HasValue ? e.ParentID == id : e.ParentID == null
                                select new
                                {
                                id = e.ID,
                                hasChildren = (from q in _context.Org
                                            where (q.ParentID == e.ID)
                                            select q
                                            ).Count() > 0,
                                OrgName = e.OrgName,
                                selected = (from s in _context.OrgAppJoin
                                            where (s.OrgID == e.ID) && (s.AppID == 2)// <--this works, this doesn't--> (s.AppID == app.ID) 
                                            select s
                                            ).Count() > 0,                           
                                ischecked = (from s in _context.OrgAppJoin
                                            where (s.OrgID == e.ID) && (s.AppID == 2)// <--this doesn't work, this doesn't either--> 
(s.AppID == app.ID)
                                            select s
                                            ).Count() > 0
                                };
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
```

My first issue is probably very simple, I'm new to this platform: I can't seem to find a way to get the value of the AppID from the page into the OnGetRead Module ( i have hard coded s.AppID == 2 as an test example to see if it works) I have tried all sorts of variables and other methods. 
The id passed into OnPostAsync and OnGetAsync is the id of the App, but the id passed into the OnGetRead is the id of the Org, which is correct and works, but how do I use the AppID from the page to replace the number two in this line? where (s.OrgID == e.ID) && (s.AppID == 2)?

My second issue is getting the checkboxes to read and write.
The DropDownTree above writes to database correctly, but doesn't read and populate checkboxes.
The Treeview doesn't populate checkboxes or write to the database, however it DOES read the selected value from the join table for app number 2 (or any other number I manually insert) in OnGetRead, and displays different font colours etc for the correct items as selected, but not as checked (aschecked may not even be a valid call theere, but I can't find a reference for that).

I feel like I'm close but I have tried for so long to get this to work to no avail, including to and fro with telerik who have tried help but they don't really help much with modelling to your own code, just with static data, and they seem to be light on for a Razor app knowledgebase and keep giving examples of controllers with hard coded data.

Please advise if I need to split this into two questions or more but any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any samples of a tree that display correctly?  You have cshtml and basically you are trying to convert the database results with the cshtml.  The cshtml is JSON so you are trying to serialize the database model to JSON.  Correct? Rather than post all the code try to simplify issue to exactly where you are having issues serializing by posting the results you currently have and the results you actually need.

Comment: Both trees display the tree correctly, the dropdowntree and the treeview, neither check the boxes they should, the dropdowntree doesn't read but saves the data correctly, the treeview neither saves nor reads, but it displays the selected property from OnGetRead as different coloured backgrounds etc as per kendo defaults for selected

Comment: You first need to get the checkboxes to work correctly.  It looks like this statement is wrong.                                .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                                          .Name("ischecked")
                                          .CheckChildren(true)) There should be an equal sign in statement setting to either True or False.